# MS Word on Mac: labels

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Im using MS Word on my Mac and cannot perfectly line up my text on my address labels. How do I move my text down just a wee bit?  Is there a key stroke to do this on a Mac?
Thanks,
Nancy

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the document you're on? (Please use a fake address) Are you writing your text normally, or are you using text boxes?